# recursive pattern match with options

Tags: recursion, pattern-matching, ocaml

When you are patterning matching in OCaml and returning an option type, you make your pattern return a `Some x` or `None`. If your pattern returns the function (recursively), would you need to put `Some` in front of it? Let me make this more clear:

example code:

```
let rec whatt (c: coding) : bool option = 
match c with
|a(a) -> Some a
|b(b) -> None
|d(x,s,l) -> Some whatt x and Some whatt s and Some whatt l
```

I'm not sure A.) if you'd need `Some` because of some value you're getting and putting back into the function and B.) I'm not sure the syntax of separating the returned values in the last line. And, &&, || ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, well the "and" operator in OCaml is `&&`. Since its arguments are `bool` and not `bool opt`, you can't have an expression `Some x && Some y`.

Furthermore, your function `whatt` (by hypothesis) returns a `bool opt` already. So you don't need to apply `Some` to it to get a `bool opt`. In other words `Some (whatt x)` has the type `bool opt opt`, which is ever farther from working.

Third, you need to decide what you want the value of your result to be if `whatt` returns None. Let's say you want to treat both `Some false` and `None` as effectively false. Then you could write something like this:

```
let bvalue = function Some b -> b | None -> false

bvalue (whatt x) && bvalue (whatt s) && bvalue (whatt l)
```

This is probably not exactly what you're looking for but maybe it will give you some ideas.